# Why is cell increment not detected correctly in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a column which I'd like to fill by selecting the top two cells and then drag down the column.
The cell contents are:

```
=Sheet1.B11
=Sheet1.B31
```

So when I drag down I expect to see

```
=Sheet1.B51
=Sheet1.B71
```

Instead, I get

```
=Sheet1.B13
=Sheet1.B33
```

Why is Calc not detecting the increment correctly? Adding more cells manually does not help.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers in cell references are not single numbers which can be used to create a series in this way. In other words: The cell reference B11 is not "B"&11, but even one single cell reference.

To get references from Sheet1.B11 upwards in steps of 20, you could use INDEX like this:

```
=INDEX($Sheet1.$B$1:$B$100000,11+(ROW(A1)-1)*20)
```

Put this formula into a cell and fill it down.

Comment: Thanks, although a formula that detects the step automatically would be even better.